# Laravel 5.1 - Login / Register User NOT WORKING

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.1

I'm creating an user control panel to manage site's contents.
As documentation reports i've my routes:

```
// Authentication routes...
Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');

// Registration routes...
Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');


Route::controllers([
   'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);
```

I've also created my views for login (login.blade.php) and register user (register.blade.php) within "auth" folder.
But once i try to register or also to login an user i get this url: http://localhost:8888/auth/register
and my page says:
Not Found The requested URL /auth/register was not found on this server.
I don't understand what's not working.

Edit:
    [template](http://pastebin.com/1Bbt4LrL)
    [Login](http://pastebin.com/vWvcSR4D)
    [Register](http://pastebin.com/bReTMrFs)

Solved:
It's a blade question, you have to insert link's behaviours by yourself: {{ url('/auth/register') }}

Comment: can u edit your question with blade files?

Comment: I assume you are using the built in `Auth` controller?

Comment: i've edited with 3 links to my blade files. Yes till now i'm using AuthController built-in but i'd like to manage everything from a custom Controller like AdminController, but i don't understund how to do it like i did with Laravel 5.0

Comment: Does anything else working? Can you provide a link that currently working? (like http://localhost:8888/auth/register )

Comment: unfortunately no because it's a private project under development, i'm really sorry

Comment: Please remove "Solved" from your title and question. You can post the answer on its own, and even accept it. That is the proper indication  for others with a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

I put this code to master blade.....

```
<a href="{{ url('/auth/login') }}">Login</a>
```

`<a href="{{ url('/auth/register') }}">Register</a>`

```
<a href="{{ url('/auth/logout') }}">Logout</a>
```

This code to route.php

```
Route::controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);
```